# Angularjs $watch() not changing values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have put a `$watch()` for an attribute of a custom directive (which in turn is a scope variable). When the value of the scope variable gets changed, the corresponding attribute values of the directives dont change and hence the value function doesnt get fired.

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- some code -->
</head>

<body>

    <div ng-controller=visCtrl class="container col-sm-12">

        <div timeline-chart vis-file=skillFile class="divVis divVisLine col-sm-12">
            <!-- some code -->
        </div>

        <div skill-chart vis-file=skillFile exp-key={{selectedDataKey}} class="divVis divVisLine col-sm-12">
            <!-- some code -->
        </div>


    </div>

    <!-- some code -->
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.utils']);

myApp.controller('visCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.selectedDataKey = 4;

});


myApp.directive('timelineChart', function($window) {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {



                    drawTimeLine = function() {
                        var chart = d3.timeline()
                            //some code
                            .click(function(d, i, datum) {
                                //console.log(scope);
                                console.log("previously selectedDataKey was:" + scope.selectedDataKey);
                                scope.selectedDataKey = datum.key;
                                console.log("selectedDataKey changed to:" + scope.selectedDataKey);
                            });

                        d3.csv(dataFile, function(error, data) {
                                //some code
                            }

                            drawTimeLine();
                        }
                    }
                });

            myApp.directive('skillChart', function($window) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'EA',
                    /*template:"<svg width='850' height='200'></svg>",*/
                    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                        var dataKey = attrs.expKey || false;

                        scope.$watch(function() {
                            return attrs.expKey;
                        }, function(value, oldval) {
                            dataKey = value || false;
                            console.log("skillChart dataKey changed to:" + dataKey);
                            if (dataKey) {
                                drawSkillChart();
                            }
                        });

                        drawSkillChart = function() {
                            //some code
                        }

                        drawSkillChart();

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: could it be that watchexpression is also missing in you question? the doc defines watch [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) what variable/model you want to be notified for.

Answer (score 0):

Check your scopes. You will probably find to variable name 'selectedDataKey' in 2 different scopes.

Use an object and nested properties instead:
visCtrl:

```
$scope.data = {
  selectedDataKey : 4
}
```

timelineChart:

```
scope.data.selectedDataKey = datum.key;
```

html:

Answer (score 0):

In your skillchart directive change scope to $scope, the directive would look like:

```
myApp.directive('skillChart', function($window) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'EA',
                    /*template:"<svg width='850' height='200'></svg>",*/
                    link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
                        var dataKey = attrs.expKey || false;

                        $scope.$watch(function() {
                            return attrs.expKey;
                        }, function(value, oldval) {
                            dataKey = value || false;
                            console.log("skillChart dataKey changed to:" + dataKey);
                            if (dataKey) {
                                drawSkillChart();
                            }
                        });

                        drawSkillChart = function() {
                            //some code
                        }

                        drawSkillChart();

                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar example and it seems to be working. If you change the value of the key in the text box, it is printing the value of the corresponding directive attribute in the console.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.selectedKey = 5;
})
app.directive('example', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watch(function(){
        return attr.expKey;
      }, function(newVal, oldVal){
        if(newVal) {
          printDataKey(newVal);
        }
      });

      var printDataKey = function(dataKey) {
        console.log("newVal is " + dataKey);
      };
    }
  }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type='text' ng-model='selectedKey'>
    <p example exp-key={{selectedKey}}>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nDI3kj4j3KPPDJP3MNcT?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

To watch the changes in directive's attribute, you need to use `$observe` instead of `$watch`. So change your code something like this:

```
 link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var dataKey = attrs.expKey || false;

      attrs.$observe('expKey', function() {
            // your code on value change
      });
 }
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes